# Lock Navigator in react-native

Tags: scrollview, react-native, navigator

Is it possible to prevent the Navigator in react-native to render the previous scene?

I'm having a conflict between a scrollView and my Navigator, I set the Navigator to render the scene FloatFromBottom, so when I scroll down it scrolls the content fine but when I try to scroll up I'm going to the previous scene.